# BizTalk 2013 R2 CU 5 Installation

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I am planning to install CU 5 for BizTalk 2013 R2. I cannot find any reviews online so I wanted to have your feedback if there are issues installing the CU 5. I am using BizTalk 2013 R2 and I haven't installed any CU updates thus far.

Link of CU upgrade - [Cumulative Update package 5 for BizTalk Server 2013 R2](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3201943/cumulative-update-package-5-for-biztalk-server-2013-r2)

Comment: No, there weren't any issues with CU5, unlike the first version of CU2 that broke BizTalk  https://cdijkgraaf.wordpress.com/2016/01/08/biztalk-2013-r2-cu2-failure-has-occurred-while-loading-a-type/

Comment: Yeah. I read issues with CU2 package here as well. thanks for the info!

Comment: Yes, there is a possible issue with CU5 if you install it without the required SQL admin rights (the installer doesn't notify about this the way it should) https://blog.jeroenmaes.eu/2017/02/could-not-find-stored-procedure-ops_clearoperationsprogress-after-biztalk-2013r2-cu5-install/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install all BizTalk CU's during regular maintenance.

It's a good idea to treat them like any other app update, meaning apply to DEV, then TEST, then PROD, applying all you regular test procedures along the way.

For clarity, all BizTalk Server CU's are cumulative so CU5 will include all updates and patches from 1-4 as well.

Comment: So does this means that I need to install CU1 then CU2 upto CU5 one by one? I thought since its cumulative update, CU5 package includes updates from CU1 to CU5.

Comment: What Johns-305 means, is that, whenever a new CU package becomes available, you should not blindly install it. First install it on your DEV. When things run smoothly there, proceed to TEST and once you are sure all of your flows run correctly, only then put them in PROD. If you now have just one CU to install (CU5), you don't need to install CU1...2, 3, etc...

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with BizTalk 2013R2 CU5 when you install it without the required SQL admin rights (the installer doesn't notify about this the way it should according to my opinion).

At the end of the installation, the installer will tell you it failed completing some post-installer steps. In the installer log file you will find a reference to the missing SQL rights.

[image: SELECT permission was denied...]

When you try to open the BizTalk Admin Console, you will encouter a '**Could not find stored procedure ops_ClearOperationsProgress**' exception.

[image: Could not find stored procedure ‘ops_ClearOperationsProgress’]

The only way to recover from this is doing a database restore of the management database.

I wrote a blog post about this [here](https://blog.jeroenmaes.eu/2017/02/could-not-find-stored-procedure-ops_clearoperationsprogress-after-biztalk-2013r2-cu5-install/).

Comment: Im trying to install the CU5 and im getting alot of errors wherein it is looking for the installer disc and the Biztalk version is not updated in Add and Remove (which the issue is encountered in CU2). I checked the dlls deployed and the only one that was updated is Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.MQS.Agent.Interop.dll. I followed the instructions provided by Microsoft.